# Display HTML in Python Notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I have generated an interactive scatter plot using the library scattertext. The scatter plot is saved in HTML file. I want to display it in a .ipynb notebook but it looks awkward.
[image]

It should look like this:
[image]

Plus Jupyter Lab crashes, some element like save bottom or run bottom become blue.
Here is my code:

```
#Compute frequency of terms based on label
corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(df_parser,category_col='Label', parsed_col='Parsed').build()

#Create Scatter plot in HTML
html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(corpus,
                                    category='True',
                                    category_name='True Fact Checks',
                                    not_category_name='False Fact Checks',
                                    width_in_pixels=1000,
                                    minimum_term_frequency=5,
                                    transform=st.Scalers.scale,
                                    metadata=df_parser['Author'])

file_name = f'{PATH}Title_scatterplot.html'
open(file_name, 'wb').write(html.encode('utf-8'))

display(HTML(html))
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there any work around like directly embedding the HTML file in the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display(HTML(html))` for Colab notebooks.

For Jupyter notebooks, write the scatter plot's HTML to a file, and display it as an iframe, using something like:
`IFrame(src=<path of html file>, width = 1300, height=700)`.